# Modelbinding when the model is repeated on the page

Tags: model-binding

I can't believe this is so hard to find but...

I have a model that will be repeated multiple times on a page. By default it names the fields the same on both models so it doesn't seem to bind properly. How do I make it so I can use the same model multiple times?

Basic context of the issue: Picture having a user that can add unlimited contacts on the same page. The contact fields are based on a model (name address phone ect), and I just enumerate through that model to show each field for each contact. The first iteration works fine, but after the first contact, nothing seems to get passed back to the model on post.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: would you mind mentioning the technology: spring mvc, rails or asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at following blog posts
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/
http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-ii.html
http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/